# Force User To change password on first time login in android

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello Coders I want some help regarding password change on first login actually i'm signing up the user with random password which i giving that password via email and then after getting random password in email when user put that password in the login screen then only first time i want to show the change password screen can any one help me out how to do this type of code

Answer (score 2):

You can save a boolean flag in your SharedPreferences and check that flag each time the application starts. Once the user changed the initial password successfully you can set the flag and then not trigger the password change functionality anymore.

```java
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

// write the preference
prefs.edit().putBoolean("USER_CHANGED_INITIAL_PASSWORD", true).apply();

// read the preference. second parameter is a default value
// it gets returned if the preference does not exist yet
boolean initialPasswordChanged = prefs.getBoolean("USER_CHANGED_INITIAL_PASSWORD", false);
```

Besides that it's not a good practive to give the user an inital password which gets sent to them by email in plain text... Better let him choose his password the first time he signs up and then send some email to confirm the email address he used. If you need to be sure it's indeed his email you can still restrict account access as long as the email is not confirmed yet.

Comment: No i'm not getting Your Point Please can u more elaborate the answer for me i will thankful for that

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?